# Dual color iOS status bar / Alter width dimensions

Tags: ios, status, multi-column

What is the best approach for dealing with the status bar when an app screen has two columns. One column is dark whilst the other is light.

1. Can the status bar show light over the dark content and dark over the light content?
2. Can the width be altered slightly (see example below).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it cannot do that out of the box: it's either light, or dark;
2. No, it's width cannot be altered normally;

I guess, you could make yourself a custom status bar, that behaves how you want it to, except it might not be a good idea, because status bar is rather functional and will require a lot of work if you want it to emulate the built-in status bar perfectly, and inevitably break user's expectations if you don't - all the different indicator icons, "previous app" button, call, capture or hotspot indicator, different settings, iPhone X, etc.

In your case I'd simply color the background of your status bar in the color of one of your columns.